# Logarithm of the n'th prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $P_n$ denote the n'th prime number. How could we conclude the following from the prime number theorem?  $$ \log(P_n)=\log n + \log\log n + o(1) $$

Maybe by showing that $P_n=An\log n $ for a suitable $A$?

Answer (score 1):

For some constants $c,C$ we have
$$ c \frac{n}{\log n} \leq \pi(n) \leq C \frac{n}{\log n}. $$
Since $\pi(P_n) = n$, we get
$$ c \frac{P_n}{\log P_n} \leq n \leq C \frac{P_n}{\log P_n}. $$
This can be manipulated to show that
$$ P_n = \log n + \log\log n + O(1). $$
If you want to reduce $O(1)$ to $o(1)$, use a better version of the prime number theorem, namely one that gives $\pi(n) = \frac{n}{\log n} + o(\frac{n}{\log n})$.

Comment: Ok. So now I'm having trouble with the $\log\log n$ instead of $\log\log P_n$ part.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to sweat a bit. The idea is that $P_n$ is close enough to $n$ that $\log\log P_n \approx \log\log n$. Work it out on your own.